# How can I use Excel to replace values in a comma separated list with values in another cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have a lookup table that looks like this:

```
ID | SKU
1  | 5123
2  | 1238
3  | 5812
```

And another table that has a comma separated list of SKU:

```
SKULIST
5123, 1238
5812, 5123
```

How can I add a column that replaces the SKU with their IDs from the first table. So the result would be like this:

```
SKULIST    | IDLIST
5123, 1238 | 1, 2
5812, 5123 | 3, 1
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I really question the use case of this.

Comment: It's for an import sheet into Shopify using a third-party tool. The tool has a limitation of only being able to identify a list of products by their internal ID or product handle, rather than SKU. We needed to transform the sku-list into a ID/handle-list for it to import correctly. The solution provided by @MGonet worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the screenshot. If your Excel version is not very old, you can use this formula.
[image: ID_SKU]

Comment: This worked great!